# Show labels in console output

Tags: r, console, dataframe, label, dplyr

I am using a labelled data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")

df= tbl_df(diamonds) %>%
  select(cut, carat, price) %>%
  set_label(c("", "Kt", "EUR")) %>%
  slice(1:3)
```

In R-Studio the data frame view looks looks as it should be:

[image]

When printing `df` to the console the `dplyr` package reformats the `tbl_df` object to:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

      cut carat price
   (fctr) (dbl) (int)
1   Ideal  0.23   326
2 Premium  0.21   326
3    Good  0.23   327
```

So with this default the labels get lost (not in the data frame, but comparing R-Studio view and console).

I am looking for a function which provides following console output (exchanging class info against labels and optionally skipping the source info):

```
      cut carat price
       ()  (Kt) (EUR)
1   Ideal  0.23   326
2 Premium  0.21   326
3    Good  0.23   327
```

Comment: Why do you need to try to change the type labels?  What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: As a user (not programmer) I want to see in interactive sessions the unit of measurement (label) rather than the classes.

Comment: Have you tried `df<-data.frame(df)`

Comment: @MaxPD Yes, certainly. But this does not give the requested output.

Comment: Paste the units of measurement into the column name.

Comment: `set_label()` sets an attribute of the columns. The print methods for `tbl_df` and `data.frame` do not make use of this attribute, so printing is not affected by it. This does not mean that the object is reformated, the labels are simply not something that `print()` takes care of. In order to show the labels, when printing a `tbl_df` object, you'll have to write your own version of `print.tbl_df()`.

Comment: @Stibu Thx, but you repeat the problem description. The reasons are well understood. I am looking for the function.

Comment: I don't think there is a function doing this, so I guess you have to write your own print-method. When writing such a function, I would not overwrite the `print.tbl_df` method, but rather write another print-function (e.g. `print.lbl_df` and then give those data frame also a `lbl_df` class sttribute) - unless you want to use this function only for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick implementation. I could add that to my `sjmisc` package, if it turns out to be useful.

```
print.lbl_df <- function(x, n = NULL, width = NULL) {
  # get labels
  dlab <- sjmisc::get_label(x)
  # if x of class tbl_df?
  if (!"tbl_df" %in% class(x))
    x <- dplyr::tbl_df(x)
  # get df matrix
  dmat <- dplyr::trunc_mat(x, n = n, width = width)
  # set labels
  for (i in 1:ncol(dmat[[1]])) {
    # replace first value of each column, which is the class description
    # with variable label
    dmat[[1]][[i]][1] <- dlab[i]
  }
  # use dplyr-print method now
  print(dmat, n = n, width = width)
}

lbl_df <- function(x) {
  # add class attribute, if necessary
  if(!"lbl_df" %in% class(x))
    class(x) <- c("lbl_df", class(x))
  x
}

library(dplyr)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")

mydf <- lbl_df(tbl_df(diamonds) %>%
  select(cut, carat, price) %>%
  set_label(c("", "Kt", "EUR")) %>%
  slice(1:3))

mydf

>       cut carat price
>              Kt   EUR
> 1   Ideal  0.23   326
> 2 Premium  0.21   326
> 3    Good  0.23   327
```

**Edit:** I've added a `lbl_df` method and a generic `print` method to my sjmisc-package, I'll commit the changes tonight. If you like, you can then install the latest version [from GitHub](https://github.com/sjPlot/sjmisc).

Comment: Thx, excellent, this is a good approach. Looking forward to the new Version. May I recommend to put the labels in round or sqaured brackets to indicate their unit nature?

Comment: I did not used brackets / braces, because there are only two rows, the first one being the column name and the second one being the variable label. The output is well readable to me, and adding brackets would widen the columns (in most cases, variable labels are longer than column names). The example above also mimics RStudio's `View`-behaviour - you don't have brackets there, neither (however, different formattings). And finally, a variable label not always has a unit-nature.